# I am trying to keep a container running using a docker compose file. I added tty: true and std_in: true but it still exits with code 0

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, yaml, docker-container

Here is my docker compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: emarcs/nginx-git
        ports:
            - 8081:80
        container_name: Avida
        working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/html
        command: bash -c "git clone https://github.com/raju/temp.git && echo "cloned successfully" && mv Avida-ED-Eco /usr/share/nginx/html && echo "Successfully moved the file""
             
        volumes:
             - srv:/srv/git
             - logs:/var/log/nginx
        environment:
            GIT_POSTBUFFER: 1048576  
        stdin_open: true 
        tty: true 
    firefox:
        image: jlesage/firefox
        ports:
            - 5800:5800
        volumes: 
            - my-vol:/data/db
        depends_on: 
            - web
volumes:
     my-vol:
        driver: local
     srv:
        driver : local
     logs:
        driver : local
```

What I am doing is I am using a docker nginx image with git installed on it and using that image to clone a directory and moving that directory to ngnix HTML path to read it. but after cloning the container exits and the code goes away. How can I keep container running without exiting with code 0. I tried some options such as tty: true and std_in: true nothing works.

[container exit with code 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRe8f.png)

Comment: Create a custom docker image and start that normally. Also don't copy everything to the html output dir (for example the .git directory). Btw the command overrides the origin image's entrypoint, so you have to start nginx to keep the container alive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set an individual container's `command:` to copy some code into the container, every time it starts up.  It'd be better to write a Dockerfile to do this work, only once.  You can start a Dockerfile `FROM` any image you want and do any setup work you need to do in the container.  It will inherit the `ENTRYPOINT` and/or `CMD` from the base image if you don't override them.

```bash
# Dockerfile
FROM emarcs/nginx-git
RUN mkdir /x
 && git clone https://github.com/raju/temp.git /x
 && mv /x/temp/Avida-ED-Eco /usr/share/nginx/html
 && rm -rf /x
# (Can you `COPY ./ /usr/share/nginx/html/` instead?)
```

Then in your Compose file, specify to `build:` an image instead of using the Docker Hub `image:`; do not override `command:`; and do not overwrite parts of the image with named volumes.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    # this is all that's required
```

Comment: Yeah I got your point of creating a docker file and building an image out of it but due to an organization requirement, I am forced to do this. Like I have to write a docker-compose file that not only I but other people can use just by using docker-compose up to build all images with one command.  The challenge is not writing a docker file but keeping running the Nginx image. It pulls and then exits I don't want it to exit. as long as it doesn't exit it still has the code in it. I know this is not an efficient way but  I want to see if there is an option coz tty:true doesn't works .

Comment: I want to know if there is a command which I can used to stop the nginx container from exiting. I searched through a lot but didn't get any suitable thing. When I do '''docker run  nginx''' it starts and never stops until I explicitly ask it to stop. Why can't I do that with a docker compose file.

Comment: Because the `command:` override is telling the container to run `git clone` and `mv` and nothing else, and once the `command:` completes the container exits.

Answer (score 1):

So keep it running.

```
    command: 
     - bash
     - -ec
     - | 
       git clone https://github.com/raju/temp.git
       echo "cloned successfully"
       mv -v Avida-ED-Eco /usr/share/nginx/html
       echo "Successfully moved the file""
       # keep it running
       sleep infinity
```

But you would rather create a Dockerfile, in which you would prepare the image.

I changed the format, you can read about `|` in YAML documentation. I replaced `&&` by `set -e`, you can read about it https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 .

---

If you want to do some modification and then start nginx, you should:

- `docker inspect` the docker image and get the command it uses, or inspect the Dockerfile the image was built with
- invoke the shell as you do and do the stuff that you want to do
- and *then* call the command that it had previously calling

Comment: yeah but I had a requirement that I need to follow that way as using this compose file anyone can view the content on their local host. anyhow the sleep infinity worked thanks

Comment: Now  I am into another issue. The clone is successful and the container does not exits but I cannot access the html file I just copied to nginx path. Any ideas ? Does sleep infinity makes it unavailable?

Comment: The only two things that will be in the container are the wrapper `bash` process and a `sleep` process; it's not running an HTTP server or anything else useful.

Comment: @DavidMaze what can I do now? Any other way than sleep infinity so I can run HTTP server and container doesn't exits?

Comment: You should be able to run the HTTP server instead of `sleep infinity`.  But the important thing is that the Compose `command:` override is the _only_ thing the container will do, and when that command completes the container will exit.